# Brainfuck Printer Generator

Tags: ruby, meta-programming, brainfuck

Given a text, this program will output a Brainfuck program, that when executed will print the text back.

> Writing Brainfuck in this style to print a sentence is pretty straightforward. Iterate over the sentence and do the following per character:
>
> - Calculate the difference between the current character and the previous
> - Write either as many `+` or `-` as the difference between characters. `+` if current character is higher than previous character, `-` if lower than previous character
> - Write `.` to print current character

**Hello, World!**

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
+++++++.
.
+++.
-------------------------------------------------------------------.
------------.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
++++++++++++++++++++++++.
+++.
------.
--------.
-------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

**The code**

```
def brainturing_printer_generator(text)
  ords = text.chars.map(&:ord)
  ("+" * ords.first + ".\n") + ords
    .zip(ords[1..-1])
    .take(ords.size - 1)
    .map {|prev, curr| (curr > prev ? "+" : "-") * (curr - prev).abs}
    .join(".\n") + ".\n"
end

print brainturing_printer_generator("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: If you don't feel like swearing, the idiomatic terms are either "Brain****" or simply "BF."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's neat, though I feel like there's a bit too much array manipulation going on.

Your friend for this, I'd argue, is the `each_cons` method, short for "each consecutive". Then you don't need the `zip`, though you do need to pad the beginning of the array.

Here's my take:

```
def brainturing_printer_generator(text)
  ords = [0] + text.chars.map(&:ord)
  ords.each_cons(2).map do |previous, current|
    delta = current - previous
    line = (delta < 0 ? "-" : "+") * delta.abs
    "#{line}."
  end.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: `each_cons` is surely a simplification over my original code, I always miss some built-in Ruby goodness :)

Comment: @Caridorc Yeah, in many reviews I've told people to read the docs for `Array` and `Enumerable` as much as they can stand :) There's so much good stuff, and it took me a while to learn that as well. Also you get a sixth sense that tells you "there must be a built-in way to do X" and a lot of the time you're right. It's almost always a good idea to just skim the list of methods, even if you've already got a solution in your head

Comment: You miss the last `.`

Comment: @Nakilon Damn, you're right. I'll fix it, thanks